# What happens to React Clean Up Function After Unmount

Tags: reactjs

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (productId && productId !== "") fetchProductDetail(productId);
    return () => {
      dispatch(removeSelectedProduct());
    };
  }, [productId]);
```

In this UseEffect function will the cleanup function be in memory if the component unmounts ? If we return to the route of the component will the cleanup function run or will it be lost forever on unmounting?

Comment: just fyi, you don't need `{}`s around your `dispatch` call here, since that's an expression, and you can omit brackets (and the need for a `return`) when using arrow functions and your function body is an expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [useEffect cleanup documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup). In your instance, `() => dispatch(removeSelectedProduct())` will run every time `productId` changes, *and* when the component finally unmounts.

The needed variables/functions will remain in scope, because they are part of a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), i.e., references to the surrounding variables that are used are bound together with the function and live as long as it lives. As long as there is a reference to something, the runtime won't garbage collect it.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was missing that it runs on unmount too, I thought it only runs on re-renders

Comment: @Aryan no problem. `useEffect` is essentially a replacement for multiple methods in the old class-based React Component structure, it's very versatile.

Comment: yeah, got done with useEffect a few days ago, currently, I'm trying to wrap my head around when to use useMemo

Comment: @Aryan I got onto the `useMemo` train pretty late, but recently I've been loving it. The basic idea is that defining a const takes some cycles (especially for a complicated const like a function or a large object or **something that calls functions to build itself**). `useMemo` will cache it, so that it doesn't recalculate every render. Also just fyi, accepting an answer [doesn't automatically upvote it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-an-answer-should-automatically-upvote-it-as-well), so if it was helpful to you don't forget to upvote.

Comment: You might be tempted to just create `consts` outside of your component, which is what I always used to do-- but in that case, they don't have the component's variables in scope, and it's often useful to have access to those.

Comment: got it, I was trying to use `useMemo` in a similar manner in a project to prevent an infinite loop caused on every `dispatch` when passing `value ={{dispatch, state}}` to a Context Provider paired with `useReducer` due to `value` being passed an object. Oh, I see, the scope thing is an interesting use case. And, I would have for sure upvoted but I don't have enough reputation, it won't let me.